# IF(ISBLANK(H1),,) or IF(H1="",,)?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

In answer to the question [How can I use Excel Formulas to return multiple values using nested IF statements if I need one of the returnable values to be blank?](https://superuser.com/q/1663561/581166) I suggested using an `IF(H1="",,)` within a nested `IF()`. In the comments, it was suggested that I

> Suggest ISBLANK(H1) in lieu of H1="".

The suggestion in the comments is valid, but why would you when you can have a repeating IF statement which follows the same pattern for ease of error finding?

Not only that but you are using 6 extra characters in the formula with `ISBLANK(H1)` rather than `H1=""`

If all you are testing for is a blank, then fine.

Is there really a right and wrong way of testing for a blank cell in Excel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good question.

Let me first answer the question that is on everyones mind.

> Do `=ISBLANK(a1)` and `=A1=""` behave the same?

No, they do not, and this will determine which of the two you would want to use.

> What is the difference between the two?

`=ISBLANK(a1)` will check if A1 is empty, eg. there's nothing in the cell. If this is true, then the formula will return TRUE. If there is a formula in A1 that returns `""`, `=ISBLANK(a1)` will return false whereas `=A1=""` will return true.

Here is an example where `=ISBLANK(a1)` will result in false to illustrate:

```
A1: =IF(1=2;"3";"")   <- will result in a blank cell
B1: =ISBLANK(A1)      <- even though we see nothing in A1, this will result in False 
                         because A1 has a formula still.
```

Which one of the two you want to use really depepends on what logic you need. If you have no nested formulas that can return blank, either is fine. `=ISBLANK(a1)` is probably going to look slightly cleaner, but other than that, it is up to you.